# If condition using logical operators

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

```
        int i=0;
    if(4||1&&++i)
    {
    printf("%d",i);
    }

O/p=0
```

But according to me o/p should be 1 due to preincrement....plz explain

Comment: Learn about short circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use `||` it will check if first condition is false then it will go to second condition and so on, however the moment it finds a true condition it will return 1.

In this case 4 is true so it will not evaluate further statements here `1 && ++i` and it will directly go to `print("%d",i);`

As you have initialize `i` to `0` it will print the value `0`.

If you want if condition to evaluate `1 && ++i` also, then in place of `||` (OR) use `&&`(AND).